# OpenGL Merging Vertex Data to Minimize Draw Calls

Tags: c++, performance, opengl

**Background**

- 2D "Infinite" World separated into chunks
- One VAO (& VBO/EBO) per chunk
- Nested for loop in chunk render; one draw call per block.

**Code**

```cpp
void Chunk::Render(/* ... */) {
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    for (int x = 0; x < 64; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 64; y++) {
            if (blocks[x][y] == 1) {
                /* ... Uniforms ... */
                glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);
            }
        }
    }
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

There is a generation algorithm in the constructor. This could be anything: noise, random, etc. The algorithm goes through and sets an element in the `blocks` array to 1 (meaning: render block) or 0 (meaning: do not render)

**Problem**

How would I go about combining these triangle strips together in order to minimize draw calls? I can think of a few algorithms to find the triangles that should be merged together in a draw call, but I am confused as how to merge them together. Do I need to add it to the vertices array and call `glBufferData` again? Would it be bad to call glBufferData so many times per-frame?

I'm not really rendering *that* many triangles, am I? I think I've heard of people who can easily draw ten-thousand triangles with minimal CPU usage (or.. millions even). So what is wrong with how I am drawing currently?

## EDIT

_[Andon M. Coleman][1]_ has given me a lot of information in the [chat][2]. I have now switched over to using instanced arrays; I cannot believe how much of a difference it makes in performance, for a minute I thought Linux's `top` command was malfunctioning. It's _very_ significant. Instead of only being able to render say.. 60 triangles, I can render over a million with barely any change in CPU usage.

Comment: *I'm not really rendering that many triangles, am I?* That's kind of your problem. Your drawing algorithm is O (N^2) and you're drawing 4 triangles at a time. Since this is a triangle strip, have you considered using degenerate triangles (primitive restart) to do the whole draw all at once?

Comment: 4 triangles at a time? I believe my glDrawElements call is only drawing two triangles to make a square. I haven't tried using primitive restart. Should I try to merge all of the vertex data (per chunk) into a VBO and use primitive restart?

Comment: A triangle strip with 6 indices is N-2 = 4 triangles. Coalescing the vertex data into a single buffer should give you tremendous performance gains, but I'm not really sure what sort of stuff is going on in the /* ... Uniforms ... */ section of the code. You may need to make those into vertex attributes to do this, since there are a limited number of uniforms available.

Comment: If I change the mode to `GL_TRIANGLES` would it be 2 triangles, or still 4? I am setting the world position data in that 'Uniforms' section. `glUniform2f(uniWorldPosition, (position.x * 64) + x, (position.y * 64) + y);` where "position" is the chunk position. Perhaps I could set a uniform ('chunkPosition') before the chunk draw that specifies the chunk location, and then have an attribute for the positions of the triangles inside the chunk?

Comment: If you use `GL_TRIANGLES` then you don't need primitive restart at all. `GL_TRIANGLES` are not connected - each 3 indices defines a separate triangle. But you would need to re-order your vertices for sure, you can't just change from a strip to a triangle list. I am actually beginning to get the impression here that what you are after is [vertex instancing](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing) - if each of these triangles has a set of uniforms that define its position, that's kind of a perfect use case for it. You might want to look at that and see if it is appropriate.

Comment: I have been looking at vertex instancing. I've been confused as to how to communicate the integer (as of right now it's just 0 or 1) from the blocks[x][y] array to determine if there should (or should not) be a block in a specific location. Am I thinking about it's use wrong?